# ScalaTestFailureLocation Expected StructField(value1,ArrayType(StringType,true),false) Actual StructField(val2,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, testing, null

I am trying to run some tests. Namely

```
assertDataFrameEquals(etalon, agg)
```

on 2 dataframes. But get the following error

```
ScalaTestFailureLocation
Expected StructField(value1,ArrayType(StringType,true),false)
Actual   StructField(value2,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
```

One df is created from a list

```
val etalon= spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF()
```

The other is calculated from some input files.

If value2 was a String or some other such type, I could do

```
etalon.na.fill()
```

on it. But this doesn't work on arrays. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code snippet, here the schema of agg dataframe is being applied to etalon dataframe so that their schema is consistent.

```
var etalon = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF()

val newSchema = agg.schema

etalon = spark.createDataFrame(etalon.rdd, newSchema)

assertDataFrameEquals(etalon, agg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question of how to fill with an arbitrary value null arrays. You could make a UDF:

`val replaceNulls = udf{ theArray: Seq[Int] => if (theArray==null) Seq.empty[Int] else theArray }`

Afterwards, you can use it:

`yourDF.withColumn("nameColumn", replaceNulls(col("arrayColumn")))`

However, this won't solve the problem you mentioned, as the StructFields of your dataframes are different in the `nullable` parameter (StructField constructor ([StructField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructField.html)):
`StructField(String name, DataType dataType, boolean nullable, Metadata metadata)`)
The answer given above (using each others schema for creating the dataframe, should work).